# angularjs $http POST special characters

Tags: http, post, angularjs, special-characters

I have a requirement to accept Special Characters (àéïôûç) in name fields.

**1)** Following JavaScript logic path HTML <form> to function w/ $http POST, the special characters are intact.

**2)** calling code:

```
     $http({

        url: formServiceUrl,

        method: 'POST',

        data: $scope.model,

        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

      }).success( ...
```

**a)** added additional header to test:  , 'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8'
      this fails too.

**3)** Chrome Devtool network tab shows:

   **INPUT {broswer console}:**

```
àéïôûç
```

**TRANSLATED to {Devtools Network POST payload}:**

```
Ã Ã©Ã¯Ã´Ã»Ã§
```

**4)** Is there an *$http* option that will send the special characters as they were entered?
    Is there something else I need to try?

Thank you

---

FYI:  
*a) Using CHROME browser only right now*

b) parent HTML page has meta-tag:

```
<meta content="IE=Edge" charset="iso-8859-1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER: Angular is appropriately encoding the data and sending to the Services Layer.
Logging out the data from services side shows it is being received correctly.

Another service is causing a 500 Internal Service Exception because it isn't handling special characters correctly.